# Angular material doesn't work correctly on ios

Tags: html, css, ios, angular, angular-material

I created a site in angular, using angular-material.
The site works on both windows and andoid with all browsers, but on ios with safari some elements are not showing (but if one clicks on the page the input fields work correctly and one can log in):

- on andorid:

[image: andorid]

- on IOS:

[image: IOS]

This is the HTML code of the page:

```
 <div class="component-login">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form name="loginForm" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="logIn(f)">
          <div class="row  pl-4">
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="full-width">
              <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
              <input  matInput required name="username" ngModel #username="ngModel"/>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <div class="row  pl-4">
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="full-width">
              <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
              <input matInput required [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'" name="password" ngModel  #password="ngModel"/>
              <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
              <mat-error *ngIf="password.dirty">
                Errore
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="center">
              <button mat-flat-button class="btn-save btn" [disabled]="!f.valid">Login</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Css Code:

```
.component-login{
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  .content{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #e10600;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      width: 90%;
    }
    img{
      margin: 60px 50px;
      @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
          margin: 60px 10px;
      }
    }
    .row{
      font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
      color: #fff;
      .col-lg-12{

        padding: 0 50px;
        ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-flex{
          border-right: 5px;
          background-color: #fff;
        }
      }
      .center{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      a{
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
        img{
          width: 4%;
          margin: 0 10px 0 0;
        }
      }
      .mat-button-disabled{
        background-color:  #fff;
      }
      .btn-save{
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you set the ios specific media query.

```
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
   /* CSS specific to iOS devices */ 
}
```

And use a more responsive value for the height and width attributes

```
height: fit-content;
```

Refer to :
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

This can also be caused by wrong usage of col attributes since, you'll need to use the size that fits the ios device's size. (try changing the  `col-lg-12 and row pl-4` attributes).

Good luck